# Eliminar con un botón dos tablas relacionadas en LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo tabla `Producto` y tabla `Imagen`. Necesito eliminar con un solo botón los dos registros. `Producto` es la tabla padre, `imagen` la tabla hija que tiene la fk de tabla producto.

La función en el controlador estoy enviando así (se que no está bien). ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $result = Producto::find($id);
        $result->delete();

        $resultImagen = Imagen::find($id);
        $resultImagen->idProducto = $result->id_producto;
        $resultImagen->delete();

        return redirect('/productos')->with('success', 'Stock has been deleted Successfully');
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenida Karen, revisa en el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) los apartados [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder obtener buenas respuestas. [Edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/259576/edit) y añade lo que has intentado hasta ahora, así como tus resultados, que error te aparece y porque dices que no está funcionando bien.

Comment: Como precaución deberías eliminar primero el registro hijo y después el padre, por si hay algún tipo de [restricción en base de datos](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html#innodb-foreign-key-generated-columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dice Fly tienes que borrar el hijo y después el padre.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    // buscas el padre
    $result = Producto::find($id);

    // buscas el hijo y lo borras
    $resultImagen = Imagen::find($result->id_producto);
    $resultImagen->delete();

    // borrar el padre
    $result->delete();

    return redirect('/productos')->with('success', 'Stock has been deleted Successfully');
}
```

Comment: Muchas muchas gracias :) eres el mejor!!

Comment: @KarenYzs jaja sin exagerar.

Comment: jajaja esque no se practicamente nada de laravel y necesito hacer un proyecto para el instituto ...